# Entity Framework, Seeding on Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

My question is, can you easily seed a third tier of data using entity framework. I know two tiers of foreign key work as I use them all the time, though will three?

My data structure is the following.

Top Level Table

**Table One - Company** (One to many of Areas)
 - *"list"* Areas

**Table Two - Areas** (One to many Items)
 - *"list"* Items

**Table Three - Items** (Many to One)
 - ItemID
Currently the syntax for two levels (Between Company and Areas) works fine:

```
var NewCompany = new Company() {

      Areas = new List<Area>(){

        Areaid = 0

   }
}
            _context.Company.Add(NewCompany);
            _context.Areas.AddRange(NewCompany.Areas);
```

The question is how to achieve the following, adding the third table as a list to Areas.

```
    var NewCompany = new Company() {

      Areas = new List<Area>(){

        Items = new List<Items>(){
         itemId= 1
       }

   }
}
            _context.Company.Add(NewCompany);
            _context.Areas.AddRange(NewCompany.Areas);
            _context.Areas.AddRange(NewCompany.Areas.Items);
```

Comment: Please use tags properly. This question is not related to sq-server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally if you specified the constraint well in database and configured the model correctly then you would not require to add the related entities (Area & Items) to the relavant entity collection.

```
var NewCompany = new Company() {
      Areas = new List<Area>(){
        Areaid = 0
        Items = new List<Item>(){
           new Item(1),
           new Item(2)
           ...
           ...
        }
   }
}

//just add newCompany instance to the entity collection rest should be automatically taken care.
_context.Company.Add(NewCompany);
//no need to write below statement.
//_context.Areas.AddRange(NewCompany.Areas);
```

Comment: You are correct. I was working off a tutorial that suggested that you must always do it the way I did it above. Removing the extra adds and having the foreign keys right worked just fine!